# Question is Not There When Flagging

Tags: support, bug, flags, duplicate-questions

I am trying to flag this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730183/objects-stuck-in-wall-collision-in-python-pygame 
for the reason it was a duplicate of my own question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958787/ball-goes-through-paddle-does-not-bounce-off-it . For some reason, when I started typing my title in the flagging window, it said that there no results for this title. I then copied the title from my profile, but the same result happened. Why does SO not recognize the existence of my question?

Comment: Can you try searching by your question id (26958787) or by its URL? It works for me, but I'm not sure if that's because I'm a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no answer for that question of yours. Duplicates are meant to have an answer (unless they're exact duplicates of another question asked by the same OP).
Thus flagging this question as a duplicate of yours is not possible.